Youtube has put my uploaded video in "Shorts". How can I move it to the "Videos" tab?
I uploaded a short video (50 seconds) to my Youtube channel. It automatically went to the "Shorts" tab. How can I move it to the "Videos" tab of my channel?

I added a clarification to the duplicate target answer.
